# Ruby on Rails Report Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, report, generator, ruport

Is there a way that I can produce a report in RoR without using Ruport or any other report generator rails plugin?

Comment: Could you elaborate on as to why you don't want to use Ruport or any other report generator plugin? The most obvious answer then would be "write your own".

Comment: Yes. What do you have in mind? In particular, what do you mean by report?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magical about a "report", you can create your own view which calculates summary data in whatever type of visualization you might need.

Comment: Hehe :) I wanted to answer in the same words

Answer (score 1):

I gave my Spanish railsconf talk about that:

http://www.slideshare.net/ferdinand13/el-ferrocarril-contra-los-arboles-muertos2
(Spanish)

You have a handful of options, any of which is a silver bullet.

I am very pleased with wicked-pdf lately.

I hope this helps you, sorry the slides are in spanish, but code samples should serve you to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Jasper Report as your report backend processing. You can design your report with Jasper's web interface and programmatically call Jasper's processing tools.

[Have a look here.](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/howtointegratejasperreports)

I hope it'll help.